# Is the data type of bid getting changed while I submit the data in HTML form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on a django project. I want to bid for an item. But when I enter a specific amount of float data it converts the type of the float data. I have been trying to solve this error for a couple of days but I didn't found a solution anywhere. This is what my bids model look like:

> **models.py**

```
class bids(models.Model):
auction = models.ForeignKey(auction_listing,on_delete=CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE)
bid = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.01)])

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.bid}"
```

Here is the view function of my code.

> **views.py**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        bform = bid_form(request.POST)
        author = request.user
        post = listing
        user = request.user
        if bform.is_valid():
            bid = bform.save(commit=False)
            biddata = bids(user=user,auction=post,bid=bid)
            biddata.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("displaylistitem",kwargs={"list_id" : list_id}))
```

> **template.html**

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="form-inline">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                {{ bform.as_table }}
                <input type="submit" name="bform" value="Submit" class="btn btn-warning text-light">  
            </div>    
               
        </form>
```

This form will redirect the user to the current page itself. But whenever I submit the form it gives this kind of weird error: [TypeError while inserting float data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWR8h.png)

Comment: Can you share what `bform` is? Also, you got the unsaved bid from the form, and you created a new bid (biddata) using that unsaved bid. Is that intentional?

Comment: Basically the error is saying the bid field of bids model is being assigned a bid model instance

Comment: bform is the variable of the form I have on my page. If I send a post request on the form called bid_form, the bform variable will accept the data from the django Modelform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give an answer without seeing `forms.py`. However, I will give an answer assuming `bid_form` is a modelform which takes `bid` as an input.

You need to change `views.py` into something like this.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        bform = bid_form(request.POST)
        author = request.user
        post = listing
        user = request.user
        if bform.is_valid():
            instance = bform.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = user
            instance.auction = post
            instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("displaylistitem",kwargs={"list_id" : list_id}))
```